# Bokeh Overlapping Bar Chart?

Tags: python, bokeh

Is it possible to do overlapping bar chart in bokeh like this example in highcharts?

http://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-placement

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You can definitely create this type of chart using Bokeh lower/mid level APIs. That will require some coding to prepare the data and the glyphs. You can create and draw 2 different sources for the background and foreground rects separately. The [plotting API docs](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/plotting.html) and the [examples on the repo](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/tree/master/examples/plotting/file) should be helpful.

As a side note, at the moment (`0.11` version) the high level Charts API does have a Bar builder function to create Bar charts with just one line but it doesn't support overlapping bars.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am actually using the Bar class from the high level Charts API. I find I have the need to drop down a level to have more controls.